# Need help in XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the input xml.

```
<catalog>
    <product>
        <product_id>1234</product_id>
        <categories>
            <category>
                <category_id>frame-shape_oval</category_id>
                <category_name>frame-shape_oval</category_name>
            </category>
            <category>
                <category_id>frame-shape_square</category_id>
                <category_name>frame-shape_square</category_name>
            </category>
            <category>
                <category_id>frame-color_tortoise</category_id>
                <category_name>frame-color_tortoise</category_name>
            </category>
            <category>
                <category_id>face-shape_oval</category_id>
                <category_name>face-shape_oval</category_name>
            </category>
            <category>
                <category_id>face-shape_square</category_id>
                <category_name>face-shape_square</category_name>
            </category>
            <category>
                <category_id>gender_men</category_id>
                <category_name>gender_men</category_name>
            </category>
            <category>
                <category_id>lens-color_gold rose</category_id>
                <category_name>lens-color_gold rose</category_name>
            </category>
            <category>
                <category_id>fit_average</category_id>
                <category_name>fit_average</category_name>
            </category>
        </categories>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

This is the expected transformation

```
<catalog>
    <product>
        <product_id>1234</product_id>
        <frame_shape>oval,square</frame_shape>
        <frame_color>tortoise</frame_color>
        <face_shape>oval,square</face_shape>
        <gender>men</gender>
        <lens_color>gold rose</lens_color>
        <fit>average</fit>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

Is this possible by xslt transformation?

1. Transforming element value as element name. For eg: `<category_id>frame-shape_oval</category_id>` becomes `<frame_shape>oval</frame_shape>`. So the text before the underscore becomes the element name and text after the underscore becomes the element value.
2. Notice that the element `<category_id>` frame-shape and frame-color are repeated for `<product>` but have different values in `<category_name>`. The values are concatenated with comma.

Comment: Please indicate whether you can use XSLT 2.0 or only 1.0.

Comment: It would be XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is rather trivial, and could be handled by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="category">
    <xsl:element name="{substring-before(category_id, '_')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(category_id, '_')"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes the substring before underscore in `category_id` will always be a valid XML element name.

For the second problem, see http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and the many, many examples of Muenchian grouping here on SO.

Answer (score -1):

You can try out the following solution. Do note that i have used node-set() of microsoft to transform the content of "temp" variable into a node set.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
      <xsl:template match="/*">
        <catalog>
          <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <product>
              <xsl:copy-of select="product_id"/>
              <xsl:variable name="temp">
                <xsl:for-each select="categories/category//category_id">
                  <xsl:element name="{substring-before(.,'_')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'_')"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($temp)/*">
                <xsl:variable name="curName" select="local-name(.)"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="(count(following-sibling::*[local-name()=$curName]) &gt; 0) and (count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=$curName]) = 0)">
                    <xsl:element name="{$curName}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                      <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[local-name()=$curName]">
                        ,<xsl:value-of select="."/>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:element>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="(count(following-sibling::*[local-name()=$curName]) = 0) and (count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=$curName]) = 0)">
                    <xsl:element name="{$curName}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                  </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </product>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </catalog>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```